# Change text just on the first <p> without using Id or Class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to change the text inside a paragraph (p) tag without using ID or Class.
The html is generated by php and the paragraphs are generated without class or id.

Is there any way to change the text just of the first paragraph tag in the form?

i am trying using

```
$(".standard-form p").html("The text has changed");
```

however, the code changes all the paragraph tags in the form.

have a look at the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tym0f35w/

Comment: Try using the `:first` selector.

Comment: @Seiyria Or the, way faster, `:first-child` selector, depending on the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, like this:

```
$(".standard-form p:first").html("The text has changed");
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tym0f35w/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
$(".standard-form p").first().html("The text has changed");
```

as stated in the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/first/)?